# Can't load mock data while mounting component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a component that should render a list of mock items. The initial value is an empty array, and I want to load mock data during component render. But it doesn't work correctly - `list` in component is empty when I try to check it out by printing in console, but Redux Devtools shows that it is not. What am I doing wrong?

Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TagsBlock from './TagsBlock';
import ActionButton from './ActionButton';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { actionLoadCoctails, actionToggleDetail } from '../actions/actionCreators';

class ResultsCoctails extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.actionLoadCoctails();
    }

    list = this.props.loadCoctails.map(({ img, name, tags}, key) => {
        const showDetail = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.props.actionToggleDetail();
        }

        return (
            <div
                className="item"
                key={`coctail-${key}`}
            >
                <a
                    href="#"
                    onClick={(e) => showDetail(e)}
                >
                    <div className="img">
                        <img src={img} alt="error" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="desc">
                        <div className="name">{name}</div>
                        <TagsBlock tags={tags}></TagsBlock>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        )
    });

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="result-coctails">
                <div className="block">
                    {this.list}
                </div>
                <ActionButton txt="morе"></ActionButton>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default connect(state => ({
    loadCoctails: state.loadCoctails
}), { actionLoadCoctails, actionToggleDetail })(ResultsCoctails);
```

Reducer

```
import { LOAD_COCTAILS } from '../constants';

const INIT_COCTAILS = [
    {
        img: 'some url',
        name: 'Cocktail Mary',
        tags: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    },
    {
        img: 'some url',
        name: 'White Russian',
        tags: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    },
    {
        img: 'some url',
        name: 'Cocktail Mary',
        tags: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    },
    {
        img: 'some url',
        name: 'White Russian',
        tags: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    },
    {
        img: 'some url',
        name: 'Cocktail Mary',
        tags: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    }
];

export const loadCoctails = (state = [], { type }) => {
    switch(type) {
        case LOAD_COCTAILS:
            return {
                ...state, ...INIT_COCTAILS
            }

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

ActionCreator

```
import {
    LOAD_COCTAILS,
    TOGGLE_DETAIL,
    LOAD_DETAIL
} from '../constants';

export const actionLoadCoctails = () => {
    return {
        type: LOAD_COCTAILS
    }
}

export const actionToggleDetail = () => {
    return {
        type: TOGGLE_DETAIL
    }
};

export const actionLoadDetail = (img, name, tags, deg, txt) => {
    return {
        type: LOAD_DETAIL,
        img,
        name,
        tags,
        deg,
        txt
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `map()` function can't work with objects - so, we should make an array and do `map()` with it:

```
const listArray = Object.values(this.props.loadCoctails);
        const list = listArray.map(({ img, name, tags}, key) => {
        .....
```